# Knockout toggle active class on click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a knockout app and within it I have a function which shows/hides elements on the page depending on the selected option. The button that has been selected to activate a particular toggle will have an 'active' class so that it 'stands out' from the others and is clearly visible that that's the selected option. My problem is that I've created a knockout function to toggle the active class but it's triggering the active state on **all** of the buttons rather than the selected button and I'm not sure why?

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.isActive = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleActive = function(data, event){
        self.isActive(!self.isActive()); //toggle the isActive value between true/false
    }
}

<button data-bind="click: toggleActive, css : {'activeStyle' : isActive}">Toggle Active</button>
<button data-bind="click: toggleActive, css : {'activeStyle' : isActive}">Toggle Active</button>
<button data-bind="click: toggleActive, css : {'activeStyle' : isActive}">Toggle Active</button>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amMup/5/

Comment: Since you've tagged jQuery, you might want to consider using jQuery's toggleClass function: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: That was a mistake; swiftly fixed. It's best not to mix knockout functions w/ jquery functions

Answer (score 7):

You only have one viewmodel for all three buttons.  That means you only have a single "isActive" flag that all buttons are bound to.

Instead, use an array of items and a foreach loop to render each one.  Here's a tweaked version of your view model:

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.items = [
        { isActive: ko.observable(false) },
        { isActive: ko.observable(false) },
        { isActive: ko.observable(false) }
        ];
    self.toggleActive = function(data, event){
        data.isActive(!data.isActive());//toggle the isActive value between true/false
    }
}

var myModel = new viewModel();

ko.applyBindings(myModel);
```

And the HTML is simplified:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.toggleActive, css : {'activeStyle' : isActive}">Toggle Active</button>
</div>
```

Note the use of `$parent` to access the parent's [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).  When you're inside a foreach loop, the binding context is the individual item pulled from the foreach loop.  By accessing `$parent` you "reach up" to the object that contains the `items` property -- which, in your case, is the viewmodel where the `toggleActive` exists.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/amMup/6/

Comment: This is great, thanks. How do I now go about making it so that there's only one active button at any one time?

Comment: There's a number of different ways.  For this example, you could do it in your toggleActive function.  Loop through all of the items and set their isActive to false and then set isActive true on the "data" item (data.isActive(true))

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have them all bound to the same observable.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/fdzqJ/

## Js

```
var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.isActive1 = ko.observable(false);
    self.isActive2 = ko.observable(false);
    self.isActive3 = ko.observable(false);

    self.toggleActive = function(data){
        data(!data());
    }
}

var myModel = new viewModel();

ko.applyBindings(myModel);
```

## HTML

```
<button data-bind="click: function(){toggleActive(isActive1)}, css : {'activeStyle' : isActive1}">Toggle Active</button>
<button data-bind="click: function(){toggleActive(isActive2)}, css : {'activeStyle' : isActive2}">Toggle Active</button>
<button data-bind="click: function(){toggleActive(isActive3)}, css : {'activeStyle' : isActive3}">Toggle Active</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
<button data-bind="click: function(){setActive('1')}, css:  buttonActive() == '1' ? 'active' : '' ">Toggle Active</button>

var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.buttonActive = ko.observable(false);
    self.buttonActive = function(index){
        self.buttonActive(index);
    }
}

var myModel = new viewModel();

ko.applyBindings(myModel);
```